# cmake with GTest on Windows: build starts test, but shared libs cannot be found

Tags: windows, dll, cmake, shared-libraries

I have created a project that is split into several directories, each of the directories creating a shared library with `add_library(SubdirectoryProject SHARED ${ALL_FILES})` in CMake.

I have a `test` subdirectory where I use

```
add_executable(unittest ${ALL_FILES})

# Dependencies
target_link_libraries(unittest
PUBLIC
    GTest::GTest
    Boost::log
    Boost::json
    magic_enum::magic_enum

    SubdirectoryProject
)

find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
enable_testing()
include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(unittest)
```

It all builds fine. However, when building the test, cmake (or GTest) is also trying to run the compiled `unittest` binary to discover the tests. On Windows, this does not work because the test binary is in its own build folder and the built (shared) DLLs from the other subprojects are in their respective folders. Windows doesn't have rpath. So executing the test binary fails with an error that it cannot find the libraries.

So what to do? Do I really have to manually copy the DLLs prior to the discovering of tests? I feel like there HAS to be a cmake-way of doing this properly and automatically, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem... even the test case dependencies would not be present in the build directory.. I don't understand how this is supposed to be done for both Linux and Windows... cross platform support

Comment: @WilderField - I've posted an answer. Not sure if SO will notify the bounty-giver about new answers.

Answer (score 9):

### Project layout and files

Here's my MRE project. For convenience, I've published this at https://github.com/alexreinking/so69978314 but everything that's needed is included in the present answer.

This is the directory structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── myLib.h
├── src
│   └── myLib.cpp
├── test
│   └── test.cpp

3 directories, 4 files
```

Here are the file contents:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(so69978314)

if (PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL)
    include(CTest)
endif ()

option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared libraries instead of static libraries" ON)

find_package(tinyxml2 REQUIRED)

add_library(myLib src/myLib.cpp include/myLib.h)
add_library(myLib::myLib ALIAS myLib)
target_link_libraries(myLib PRIVATE tinyxml2::tinyxml2)
target_include_directories(
    myLib PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>")
set_target_properties(myLib PROPERTIES WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS YES)

if (BUILD_TESTING)
    find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
    include(GoogleTest)

    add_executable(unittest test/test.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(unittest PRIVATE GTest::gtest GTest::gtest_main myLib::myLib)

    if (WIN32)
        add_custom_command(
            TARGET unittest POST_BUILD
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:unittest> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:unittest>
            COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
        )
    endif ()

    gtest_discover_tests(unittest)
endif ()
```

```
// include/myLib.h
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

bool validate_xml(const char *xml);

#endif
```

```
// src/myLib.cpp
#include "myLib.h"

#include <tinyxml2.h>

bool validate_xml(const char *xml) {
  tinyxml2::XMLDocument doc;
  doc.Parse(xml);

  return doc.ErrorID() == 0;
}
```

```
// test/test.cpp
#include <myLib.h>

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

namespace {

TEST(MyLibTest, Success) { ASSERT_TRUE(validate_xml("<element/>")); }
TEST(MyLibTest, Fail) { ASSERT_FALSE(validate_xml("<foo></bar>")); }

} // namespace
```

### Explanation

There are two Windows-specific CMake settings here. The first one may be applied unconditionally:

```
set_target_properties(myLib PROPERTIES WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS YES)
```

This is for convenience... Linux and macOS shared libraries export all their symbols by default, while Windows does the Right Thing<sup>tm</sup> and only exposes those that are explicitly exported. I thought that was too much for a StackOverflow answer, so this is a shortcut.

A more principled approach would set:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)
set(CMAKE_VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN YES)
```

and use the `GenerateExportHeader` module to control symbol visibility.

Now, the real meat that makes testing work for the various shared libraries is this:

```
if (WIN32)
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET unittest POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:unittest> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:unittest>
        COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
    )
endif ()
```

This uses a new feature in CMake 3.21: the `$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:>` generator expression. On DLL platforms, it expands to the transitive list of DLLs on which the given target depends. In this case, it will be Google Test's two libraries (`gtest.dll`, `gtest_main.dll`), TinyXml2's library (`tinyxml2.dll`), and the internal `myLib.dll`.

This is passed to `cmake -E copy_if_different` to place these DLLs next to the `unittest` binary. The destination directory is given by `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:unittest>`.

The custom command is guarded by `if (WIN32)` because `$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:unittest>` will be empty otherwise. In that case, the `cmake -E copy_if_different` command won't get enough arguments and will fail at build time.

Finally `COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS` makes sure that the semicolon-delimited list returned by `$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:unittest>` is split into multiple arguments, rather than being passed as a single argument with escaped semicolons.

To see that this works on Windows, check the output logs of the relevant GitHub Actions workflow: https://github.com/alexreinking/so69978314/runs/6546304512?check_suite_focus=true

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already an old question but for future reference I though my findings in relation to this question may be helpful for others.

An alternative to copying the dlls with a POST_BUILD custom command is to add the directories where the linked libraries live to the runtime path for the test. This can be done with ENVIRONMENT_MODIFICATION:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/ENVIRONMENT_MODIFICATION.html

Automating the creation of the path took me a bit of trial and error though. Not sure it's perfect but this worked for me:

```
# There is no rpath on windows -> use cmake hack
# to help ctest find the dlls
function(getpathsforctest path_list target)
  get_target_property(libs ${target} LINK_LIBRARIES)
  set(lib_paths "")
  foreach(lib ${libs})
    set(lib_file "")
    if (TARGET ${lib})
      get_target_property(lib_file ${lib} LOCATION)
    elseif(EXISTS ${lib})
      set(lib_file ${lib})
    endif()
    if(EXISTS ${lib_file})
      get_filename_component(lib_path ${lib_file} DIRECTORY)
      cmake_path(NATIVE_PATH lib_path NORMALIZE lib_path)
      list(APPEND lib_paths ${lib_path})
    endif()
  endforeach()
  list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES lib_paths)

  if(WIN32)
    list(JOIN lib_paths "\\\;" lib_paths)
  else()
    list(JOIN lib_paths ":" lib_paths)
  endif()
  
  set(${path_list} ${lib_paths} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

add_test(NAME exampletest COMMAND exampletest)
if(WIN32)
  getpathsforctest(test_paths exampletest)
  set_property(TEST exampletest PROPERTY ENVIRONMENT_MODIFICATION "PATH=path_list_prepend:${test_paths}")
endif()
```

https://github.com/cai4cai/PyTorchFromCPPTest/blob/1217915c6d4a17e6c8a7783ba89804370dc11477/CMakeLists.txt#L92-L126